# Is W a subspace of $\mathbb{P}_3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> $W=\{p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_3 \mid p(-1)=p(2)=0\}.\\ $Is $W$ a subspace of $\mathbb{P}_3$?

Note that $\mathbb{P}_3$ denotes the vector space of all polynomials with degree of 3 or lower.

I'm not sure how to do this for $\mathbb{P}_3$, but I do know how to determine is something is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$: check if it passes the Subspace Test.

For $w_1,w_2,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$1.$ $\textbf{0}\in W$

$2.$ If $w_{1},w_{2}\in W \implies (w_1+w_2)\in W$

$3.$ If $ w \in W$, then $aw \in U\ \forall a\in \mathbb{R}$

I'm not sure how to extend this; perhaps the change of vector space from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{P}_3$ is confusing me.

Comment: The subspace test applies to any vector space.

Comment: Eh bien, why don't you see the polynomial space as an isomorphism of the $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Think of the polynomial space as $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}=\mathbb{R}^4$ you mean, because $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p_{1}, p_{2} \in W$. Then:

$(p_{1} + p_{2})(-1) = p_{1}(-1)+p_{2}(-1) = 0 + 0 = 0$

and

$(p_{1} + p_{2})(2) = p_{1}(2)+p_{2}(2) = 0 + 0 = 0$

So $p_{1} + p_{2} \in W$.

Similarly, for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$,

$(cp_{1})(-1) = c\cdot p_{1}(-1) = c \cdot 0 = 0$

and

$(cp_{1})(2) = c\cdot p_{1}(2) = c \cdot 0 = 0$

So $cp_{1} \in W$.

Finally, note that the $0$ polynomial is clearly in $W$. Hence, $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{P}_{3}$.

Nothing fancy here. The tests are the same as the tests you perform to identify subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The challenging thing here is understanding what the operations $+$ and $\cdot$ mean in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$. Once you do that, it is a matter of performing checks that you already know. :)

Comment: I think the condition $ p(x)\in \mathbb{P}_3 \mid p(-1)=p(2)=0$ is confusing me. Can you give me some examples that have this property?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: Don't you know how to find polynomials with specified roots?

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking this... for $p(-1)=0$ would an example be $x+1$?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: that's right. The condition $p(-1) = 0$ with $p \in \mathbb{P}^{3}$ just means any polynomial of degree 3 or lower with $-1$ as a root. Here's another one: $(x+1)(x-2)$. This is an example of a polynomial in $W$, i.e. a polynomial in $\mathbb{P}^{3}$ satisfying $p(-1) = p(2) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks.